# Stationarity of growth hypothesis

Tags: time-series

I have two time series that demonstrate the evolution of number of papers published in Pubmed: the total number of papers and the number of papers contatining *'holy grail'* in the text.
[image: Two plots depicting the growth of the number of ‘holy grail’ tokens and the total number of papers published in PubMed]

I want to test the hypothesis if the number of *'holy grail'* tokens will grow at the same rate as the total number of papers, so that the proportion of those papers to the total will be constant. What is the best way to test that?

Comment: A linear model to estimate the trend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing - VAR model. A statistical model called vector autoregression (VAR) is used to depict the relationship between various quantities as they change over time. With the help of this model you would be able to identify , if "holy grains" token are related to the total number of papers and vice-versa